# SQLite : cannot find table C3

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am creating a program with a SQLite database.

I have connected to the database, but the table can't be found..

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=DataAlternatif.sqlite");
try
{
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Succeed");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("not Succeed");
}
```

Connection can be established

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Customer (CustomerID) values (10)";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Cannot find table customer.

This is the database

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with full path to db like below

```
SQLiteConnection conn = 
  new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=E:\Kuliah 4\APH2\AHP2\DataAlternatif.sqlite;Version=3;");
```

Comment: the connection not succeed,mr damith

Comment: Ok then put it to folder like E:\Database` and set connection as `@"Data Source=E:\Database\DataAlternatif.sqlite"`

Comment: So what was the exact issue? I thought that this is due to Spaces in the folder path or adding `Version=3` in the connection string

Comment: i dont know sir, but if i use @"Data Source=E:\Database\DataAlternatif.sqlite" the connection is success and can find the table, but if i use @"Data Source=E:\Kuliah 4\APH2\AHP2\DataAlternatif.sqlite;Version=3;" cannot connect the DB